# How to submit form in the same way with button click and pressing 'enter'

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that's currently submitting a function when the button is clicked as below and receiving a value with an ajax request (the code below works when button is clicked). How can I get the form to also work on pressing 'enter' (which currently gives a 405 error)?

I've tried various onSubmit functions but they seem to be more for validation. I'm sure I've done this before.. Just am finding it hard to find the answer to this online. I think I can make a new event listener on the form to do this, but what is the best neatest way that is generally done, maybe without going into the script tag?

```
    <form method="post">
            Check if domain available: <input type="text" name="domainURL" id="domainURL">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="checkURLs(this.form.domainURL.value)">
            do it</button>
    </form>

<div id="availableDomains"></div>



<script>
    const checkURLs = (domainURL) => {
        document.querySelector('#availableDomains').innerHTML = 'Loading...'
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.querySelector('#availableDomains').innerHTML = ''
                responseArray = this.responseText.split(/\n/);
                responseArray.forEach(bit => {
                    var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
                    document.querySelector('#availableDomains').appendChild(newDiv)
                    newDiv.innerHTML = bit
                })
            }
        };
        xhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/domainfinder/domain/' + domainURL, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

this is my express server code just incase

```
const whois = require('whois-info');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/domainfinder/domain/:domainURL', (req, res) => {
  const domainURL = req.params.domainURL;

  //fix CORS issues
  res.set({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  })

  let tests = [domainURL];
  [...tests].forEach(domain => {
    whois.lookup(domain)
      .then(data => res.send(data))
      .catch(e => console.log(domain, e.message))
  })
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 fixes:

1. Use `onSubmit` attribute on the form and give it submit handler function. In the function use `serializeArray` to get the forms' values.
2. You can define a submit button like you did, but you should use `input` with `type="submit"`.
3. After the 2 fixes above, whenever the user is in an input and clicked `enter`, or when the user is clicking on the submit button, the submit function will be called.

NOTE: `serializeArray` is working with jQuery only! If you are using only js you can retrieve the data in different ways.

NOTE 2: I returned a false value from the `checkURLs` function and return that value in the `onSubmit` attribute, Other wise the form will vanish from the snippet.

```js
function checkURLs() {
  console.log($('#form1').serializeArray());
  // do whatever you want here
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return checkURLs()">
  Check if domain available:
  <input type="text" name="domainURL" id="domainURL">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input id="clickMe" type="submit" value="clickme">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the type to 'submit'

```
<form method="post">
        Check if domain available: <input type="text" name="domainURL" id="domainURL">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button id="clickMe" type="submit" value="clickme" onclick="checkURLs(this.form.domainURL.value)">
        do it</button>
</form>
```

Comment: HTTP ERROR 405 on both click and 'enter' now, with my code clicking the button worked

Comment: the button is calling an ajax request.. not sure what you mean by valid address?

Comment: can you post your whole code? where is `checkURLs ` defined for example?

Comment: You don't have an element with `id` of `availableDomains`, but you have used it in your code.

Comment: i do i have included it in above code now, the code above works and values are returned into availableDomains div when the button is clicked, it just gives 405 error when enter is pressed instead, thats the issue

Comment: to troubleshoot error 405, check out https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/405-method-not-allowed and https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/http-405-method-not-allowed. This error "indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource".